# Using pattern number in "UTS#35"

Tags: javascript, dojo

Using UTS#35, how would the PATTERN be to display a number in the following format: "##-########-#" ?

Comment: What did you try? Could you provide us the minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I need to display an 11 digit number in the following format: "##-########-##".
Now I am putting: "##,########,##".
But I would like to change the commas to minus signs.
I would like to know if there is a pattern that allows that.